# Help me check the values for capacitors in a reference design

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, reference

I have the following circuit diagram from documentatoin for an MC34167 which I'd like to use in a project.

[image: Circuit Diagram for MC34167]

Am I correct in assuming the capacitors are all in pF? which would give me:-

- 330pF
- 4700pF
- 0.1pF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitor values will all be in microfarads (uF).

So:

- 330uF
- 4700uF
- 100nF

You can tell that at least one of them is not in pF as a 0.1pF capacitor would be next to impossible to find and the stray capacitance from everything else would be much more than that anyway.

Generally input and output smoothing capacitors on power supplies are in the microfarad range. For switching regulators they are quite large as there are high switching currents an the output is choppy, so 4700uF at the output is reasonable.

Comment: Also, the 330 and 4700 capacitors are shown as polarized, and polarized capacitors are (almost?) always larger than 1 uF.

Comment: A bit sloppy of the designer not to add capacitor scaling like we normally see. pF / nF / uF, etc.